# Hosts file in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hosts-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with the hosts file under windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/47554/problem-with-the-hosts-file-under-windows-7)

I'm using Windows 7 Pro. I'm trying to add a new entry to Hosts file. But that entry doesn't seem to work.

> 1. Browse to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories
> 2. Right click "Notepad" and select "Run as administrator"
> 3. Click "Continue" on the UAC prompt
> 4. Click File -> Open
> 5. Browse to "%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\"
> 6. Change the file filter drop down box from "Text Documents (*.txt)" to
>      "All Files (*.*)"
> 7. Select "hosts" and click "Open"
> 8. Added a new line "127.0.0.1        somedomain.com" and close Notepad.  Saved when prompted.

I can then ping the somedomain.com, I get response from 127.0.0.1, but  when I open somedomain.com in browser. It doesn't open 127.0.0.1 instead it opens the site. How come?

I also did:

1. cleared Firefox's cache & restarted it.
2. [I've stopped "DNS Client Service"](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/forum/windows-xp/24572-windows-hosts-files-doesnt-work.html) (`%SystemRoot%\svchost.exe -k NetworkService`)
3. I flushed DNS cache from command line (`ipconfig /flushdns`)

Still no luck. What seems to the problem? I've [found same question on microsoft forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/cfe4ba80-fd63-4269-952e-f8c4ca87459b) but there was no answer there. Can some on help?

Comment: A [very similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/47554/problem-with-the-hosts-file-under-windows-7) has been asked here before. Do any suggestions there work for you?